# Why the loop is adding 1st value at last index in desc data fetch using push-shift

Tags: javascript, php

I am fetching some data from a database in descending order with respect to date and adding it to an array through loop using shift-push as new data keeps arriving periodically.

One strange thing I cannot understand is why the 1st fetched value is added to last index.

**Here is my code:**

```
function dspChrt3(Device_Data) { 
        //console.log(Device_Data);

        var time_Array = [];
        var meas_value_Array = [];

       for(var i=0; i<Device_Data.length; i++) {
            time_Array.push(Device_Data[i].date_time);
            meas_value_Array.push(Device_Data[i].meas_value);
            }

        //console.log(Device_Data[0].date_time);
        //console.log(Device_Data[1].meas_value);
        date_time = Device_Data[0].date_time;
        meas_value = Device_Data[1].meas_value;
        time_Array.shift();
        time_Array.push(date_time);
        meas_value_Array.shift();
        meas_value_Array.push(meas_value);

        console.log(time_Array);
     }
```

**Here is the console.log(time_Array); output**

```
(12) […]
​0: "2018-12-10 11:45:16"
​1: "2018-12-10 11:30:16"
​2: "2018-12-10 11:15:16"
​3: "2018-12-10 11:00:16"
​4: "2018-12-10 10:45:16"
​5: "2018-12-10 10:30:16"
​6: "2018-12-10 10:15:16"
​7: "2018-12-10 10:00:16"
​8: "2018-12-10 09:45:16"
​9: "2018-12-10 09:30:16"
​10: "2018-12-10 09:15:16"
​11: "2018-12-10 12:00:19"
​length: 12
```

// the loop should start from 12:00 but its last value.

**Here is php:**

```
<?php
    require("Connection.php");
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("Select date_time FROM soil_measurements order by date_time desc limit 12");
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $WData = $stmt->fetchAll();
    ?>
    <script>
      var WData = <?php echo(json_encode($WData));?>;
      //console.log(WData);
      //console.dir(WData);
    window.onload(dspChrt3(WData));
    </script>    
 </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

**var_dump()**

*array(12) { [0]=> array(2) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-10 12:15:16" ["meas_value"]=> int(106) } [1]=> array(2) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-10 12:00:19" ["meas_value"]=> int(106) } [2]=> array(2) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-10 11:45:16" ["meas_value"]=> int(106) } [3]=> array(2) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-10 11:30:16" ["meas_value"]=> int(106) } [4]=> array(2) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-10 11:15:16" ["meas_value"]=> int(106) } [5]=> array(2) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-10 11:00:16" ["meas_value"]=> int(106) } [6]=> array(2) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-10 10:45:16" ["meas_value"]=> int(106) } [7]=> array(2) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-10 10:30:16" ["meas_value"]=> int(107) } [8]=> array(2) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-10 10:15:16" ["meas_value"]=> int(107) } [9]=> array(2) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-10 10:00:16" ["meas_value"]=> int(107) } [10]=> array(2) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-10 09:45:16" ["meas_value"]=> int(107) } [11]=> array(2) { ["date_time"]=> string(19) "2018-12-10 09:30:16" ["meas_value"]=> int(107) }*

Comment: Edit your question with dump of `$WData`, please.

Comment: // the loop should start from 12:00 but its last value. Are you not removing the first element in the array with .shift() and adding it to the end of the array with .push()?

Comment: may be I don't understand your case clearly, but when you shift the array that means to remove the first element, then after pushing it again, it's expected to be at the last index !

Comment: @D.Dimitrov: I added

Comment: [Array.prototype.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop works fine, the code that follows it is the one that breaks the things:

```
date_time = Device_Data[0].date_time;
meas_value = Device_Data[1].meas_value;
time_Array.shift();
time_Array.push(date_time);
meas_value_Array.shift();
meas_value_Array.push(meas_value);
```

The first line extracts in `date_time` the value that has already been stored in `time_Array[0]` in the `for` loop.
The 3<sup>rd</sup> line (`time_Array.shift();`) removes the first element of `time_Array` and moves all the other elements one position toward its beginning.
The 4<sup>th</sup> line (`time_Array.push(date_time);`) puts the value stored by the first line in `date_time` at the end of `time_Array`. Remember that it is the same value that has been removed from the array on the previous step (the previous value of `time_Array[0]`).

The other three lines are even weirder. They do similar things to `meas_value_Array` (remove its first value, add another value to its end) but they use the value already stored in `meas_value_Array[1]`. In the end, `meas_value_Array` looses the first value received from the database and contains the second value duplicated at both its ends.

What's the purpose of these 6 lines? They don't make any sense and they don't match the expected outcome you described in the question.

---

**Update (what I think I understood after the discussion with the OP in comments)**

The statement

```
window.onload(dspChrt3(WData));
```

is a one-time initialization that copies the values from `WData` into `time_Array` and `meas_value_Array` arrays.

For this purpose, the `for` loop in the `dspChrt3()` function is enough, there is no need for anything else after it:

```
function dspChrt3(Device_Data) { 
    // Declaring this variables using `var` makes them local to this function
    // and not visible outside it. I removed the `var` keyword from here
    time_Array = [];
    meas_value_Array = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < Device_Data.length; i ++) {
        time_Array.push(Device_Data[i].date_time);
        meas_value_Array.push(Device_Data[i].meas_value);
    }
}
```

Next, if new data is retrieved somehow from the server after the page has been loaded, this function can be used to put the new data in front of the existing data and remove the old entries:

```
function updateChrt3(newData) {
    for (var i = newData.length - 1; i >= 0; i --) {
        // remove the last element of time_Array
        time_Array.pop();
        // insert a new element in front of time_Array
        time_Array.unshift(newData[i].date_time);

        meas_value_Array.pop();
        meas_value_Array.unshift(newData[i].meas_value);
    }
}
```

*(there are faster ways to achieve the same purpose but they are not the subject of this question)*

Comment: the purpose of these lines as I tried is to assign values from loop to array through var and then remove last value, move all elements one step and add new value to start of loop ao each new value start coming at the beginning of array and one last being removes and keep doing it.
Can you please help putting it in right form to achieve it.

Comment: Sorry to say but I don't understand a word from your comment. Try to make it clear (for you, in the first place) **what** do you want to achieve, not **how**.

Comment: sorry I tried to make it clear. Firstly populate the array with the data fetched from device_data. then when each time new date comes, remove last value that's the oldest one and add new value in the beginning. Like 12:00, 11:45, 11:30, 11:15.11:00. Remove 11:00 and new array is 12:15, 12:00, 11:45, 11:30, 11:15

Comment: `window.onload(dspChrt3(WData));` is a one-time initialization; it populates the arrays with the data from `Device_Data`. I cannot find the part with "when each time new date comes" in the code you posted.

Comment: Either way, [`Array.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) removes the last element and [`Array.unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) inserts a new element in front of the array and moves all the existing entries one position towards its end (to make room for the new entry).

Comment: I updated the answer with what I think you want to achieve. Maybe I'm wrong regarding your goal.

Comment: thank you very much, sorry for delayed reply. I was busy with making my graph stuff working as I have to use it there. Done with that. It looks fine though with two functions, I will need to find a way how to use it in chart.js or try to merge these somehow.

Answer (score 1):

`.push()` always adds new items to the end of the array.

Try using `.unshift()` to add items to the beginning of the array.

Comment: OK, but why not in sequence  ?? One value goes out of sequence.

Comment: It's because you're adding Device_Data[0].date_time to the end of your array by going time_Array.push(date_time).

Comment: I want the date to be appeared in desc order like 12:00, 11;:45, 11:30 ....

Comment: Remove time_Array.shift(), because by doing that you're removing the first item from the array.

Comment: Removing time_Array.shift() doesnä't make any difference.

Comment: Remove both time_Array.shift() and time_Array.push(date_time).